# `bun run`, break try/catch loop without any errors

Tags: typescript, bun

I have a problem with 'bun run'. When I run this script using 'bun run', I notice that the htmlExtractor function encounters an issue with the try/catch block. As a result, 'bun' breaks and I don't see any error.

For example, when I run the same script using ts-Node, the try/catch block works correctly.

Below is the corrected script:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import UserAgent from 'user-agents';

const userAgent = new UserAgent({ deviceCategory: 'desktop' });

async function axiosSetup() {
    const requestOptions = {
        timeout: 10000,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': userAgent.toString(),
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
        }
    };

    const fullUrl = `https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n:16225007011,n:3012292011`;

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(fullUrl, requestOptions);
        return response; // Return the actual response
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error("Error in axiosSetup:", error.message);
        throw error; 
    }
}

async function htmlExtractor() {
    try {
        const response = await axiosSetup();
        const dom = new JSDOM(response.data); // Use response.data here
        const document = dom.window.document;

        const title = document.querySelector('title')?.textContent?.trim() || 'No title found';

        return title;
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(`Error in htmlExtractor:`, error.message);
        return 'Error extracting title';
    }
}

(async () => {
    for (let length = 0; length < 3; length++) {
        try {
            console.log(`Iteration ${length}`);
            const title = await htmlExtractor();
            console.log(title); // Output the extracted title
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error(`Error occurred while processing:`, error.message);
        }
    }
})();

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
});
```

Log from `bun run`: Each run should have Iteration 0-2.

```
bun run ./src/test/test.ts
> Iteration 0
bun run ./src/test/test.ts
> Iteration 0
> Amazon.com
> Iteration 1
> Amazon.com
> Iteration 2
bun run ./src/test/testts
> Iteration 0
```

Log from `ts-node`, working well, each run has Iteration 0-2:

```
ts-node ./src/test/test.ts
> Iteration 0
> Error in axiosSetup: Request failed with status code 503
> Error in htmlExtractor: Request failed with status code 503
> Error extracting title
> Iteration 1
> Error in axiosSetup: Request failed with status code 503
> Error in htmlExtractor: Request failed with status code 503
> Error extracting title
> Iteration 2
> Error in axiosSetup: Request failed with status code 503
> Error in htmlExtractor: Request failed with status code 503
> Error extracting title
ts-node ./src/test/test.ts
> Iteration 0
> Amazon.com
> Iteration 1
> Amazon.com
> Iteration 2
> Amazon.com
```

---

EDIT
ps.
I prepared a simplified version of this script and noticed that the problem only occurs on amazon.com. Specifically, the issue occurs on https://httpstat.us/503 when the error is also 503.

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function httpRequest503Test() {
    const url = 'https://amazon.com'; // This URL is known to return a 503 error for testing purposes

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        console.log('Response received:', response.status);
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error during HTTP request:', error.message);
    }
}

(async () => {
    console.log('Starting HTTP 503 error test');
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        console.log(`Test iteration: ${i + 1}`);
        await httpRequest503Test();
    }
    console.log('Test completed');
})();

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
    console.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', promise, 'reason:', reason);
});
```